# Not able to save permission

Tags: rally

I am attempting to create new project permissions for a user/project but the save is failing because "No valid Project provided".  Looking at the network logs the RequestPayload in the server call is empty ({"ProjectPermission":{}}).  Any ideas?

```
    _addViewPermission: function() {
        this.getModel().then({             
            success: this.createPP,
            scope: this
        }).then({                          
            success: this.readPP,
            scope: this
        }).then({                          
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('success', result);
            },
            failure: function(error) {
                console.log('oh noes!', error);
            }
        });
    },            

    getModel: function() {
        return Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'ProjectPermission'
        });
    },

    createPP: function(model) {
        var permission = Ext.create(model, {
            Project: "/project/51063976712",
            Role: 'Viewer',
            User: "/user/43049588391"
        });

        return permission.save();
    },

    readPP: function(permission){
        console.log(permisson);
        return permission.self.load(permission.getId(), {
            fetch: ['Project', 'User', 'Role']
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a longstanding strange defect in the AppSDK- sorry it tripped you up!  I tried to find another stackoverflow post on it, but maybe it hasn't been asked here yet.

Anyway, the reason it is failing for you is that the Project field is marked as readonly even though it is required on create.  So the proxy never sends along the project field even though you clearly specified it.

The workaround is to simply mark the project field as persistable before creating and saving a new record.

```
model.getField('Project').persist = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I had not found that in my searches either. I inserted the line before the permission object was created and start to see data in the payload.